# Javascript, How to get zipped .csv file from URL and store it in a text string variable

Tags: javascript, csv, zip

I am not an expert in Javascript. I looked up some zip.js files but have no clue how to work with it.
All I want to do in my .html file which has some  parts is to be able to get the zipped .csv from

http://www.bclc.com/documents/DownloadableNumbers/CSV/649.zip

automatically uncompress it and set a string variable to the file content so I can parse it manually when the .html is loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because your `html` page will be run in a browser, I recommend not using it for file manipulations (extracting the zip and reading from unzipped file). Have a look at node. You might want to create an API to achieve the exact same :)

Comment: I want it to run in browser, though.  Like getting JSON, but except from a zipped URL.  That's the functionality I want in order to always get fresh data.

Comment: Umm yes. So the API would do the work of fetching the zipped file, unzipping it, reading the data and pass it forward as JSON to your frontend to process. Once received on your frontend, you can manipulate the JSON as you want

Comment: so how do I do that? I am very not expert!